# Running thread periodically every 20 ms fails

Tags: c++, c++11, timer, pthreads

currently i am programming for an embedded application which reads values from sensors periodically. I want them to be read, every 20 ms.

Im using this [tutorial](https://2net.co.uk/tutorial/periodic_threads)

```
struct periodic_info {
    int sig;
    sigset_t alarm_sig;
};

static int make_periodic(int unsigned period, struct periodic_info *info)
{
    static int next_sig;
    int ret;
    unsigned int ns;
    unsigned int sec;
    struct sigevent sigev;
    timer_t timer_id;
    struct itimerspec itval;

    /* Initialise next_sig first time through. We can't use static
       initialisation because SIGRTMIN is a function call, not a constant */
    if (next_sig == 0)
        next_sig = SIGRTMIN;
    /* Check that we have not run out of signals */
    if (next_sig > SIGRTMAX)
        return -1;
    info->sig = next_sig;
    next_sig++;
    /* Create the signal mask that will be used in wait_period */
    sigemptyset(&(info->alarm_sig));
    sigaddset(&(info->alarm_sig), info->sig);

    /* Create a timer that will generate the signal we have chosen */
    sigev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sigev.sigev_signo = info->sig;
    sigev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = (void *)&timer_id;
    ret = timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &sigev, &timer_id);
    if (ret == -1)
        return ret;

    /* Make the timer periodic */
    sec = period / 1000000;
    ns = (period - (sec * 1000000)) * 1000;
    itval.it_interval.tv_sec = sec;
    itval.it_interval.tv_nsec = ns;
    itval.it_value.tv_sec = sec;
    itval.it_value.tv_nsec = ns;
    ret = timer_settime(timer_id, 0, &itval, NULL);
    return ret;
}

static void wait_period(struct periodic_info *info)
{
    int sig;
    sigwait(&(info->alarm_sig), &sig);
}

static int thread_1_count;
```

The Main:

```
int main(){



    pthread_t t_1;
    pthread_t t_2;
    sigset_t alarm_sig;
    int i;

    printf("Periodic threads using POSIX timers\n");

    /* Block all real time signals so they can be used for the timers.
       Note: this has to be done in main() before any threads are created
       so they all inherit the same mask. Doing it later is subject to
       race conditions */
    sigemptyset(&alarm_sig);
    for (i = SIGRTMIN; i <= SIGRTMAX; i++)
        sigaddset(&alarm_sig, i);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &alarm_sig, NULL);

    pthread_create(&t_1, NULL, thread_1, NULL);
    sleep(10);
    printf("Thread 1 %d iterations\n", thread_1_count);
    return 0;
```

My Problem now, i measured the time with high resolution clock with a period of 20ms.

```
static void *thread_1(void *arg)
{
    struct periodic_info info;

    printf("Thread 1 period 10ms\n");
    make_periodic(20000, &info);
    while (1) {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        printf("Hello\n");
        thread_1_count++;
        wait_period(&info);
        auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms_double = finish - start;
        std::cout << ms_double.count() << "ms\n";
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The output i get ist:

```
...
19.8556ms
19.8587ms
19.8556ms
19.8543ms
19.8562ms
19.8809ms
19.7592ms
19.8381ms
19.8302ms
19.8437ms
...
```

So my Question, why is the Time shorter than my Period time, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe the printing at the end takes 200 µs. Try printing absolute times instead and compute the differences yourself. Also you shouldn't mix printf and cout, pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more accurate, don't take time twice on each iteration, keep the last value, like this:

```
static void *thread_1(void *arg)
{
    struct periodic_info info;

    printf("Thread 1 period 10ms\n");
    make_periodic(20000, &info);
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (1) {
        wait_period(&info);
  
        auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms_double = finish - start;
        std::cout << ms_double.count() << "ms\n";
        start = finish;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

This way, it will make the time measuring more accurate.

Comment: `20.0012ms
19.9994ms
20.0008ms
20ms
19.9998ms
20.0014ms
20.0004ms
20.0006ms
`

Thank you !